# changed mysql password and now it doesn't start

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords, debian

I am using Debian 6 and I want to reset/recover my mysql password,

I did a mistake and changed my mysql user password with the command

```
$ passwd mysql
```

but it did made the mysql service doesn't start anymore, when I do a `/etc/init.d/mysql start` it fails, can you guys help me? the mysql.err and mysql.log don't do nothing, thanks!

EDIT:

I discovered the solution: an apt-get instal --reinstall mysql-server fixed the problem, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The mysql user should not be a login account, and therefore should not have a password. I don't know why this would cause the service to not start, but you can always try using `vipw -s` to remove the password hash for the mysql user.

If you could provide the error you're getting we might have a bit more insight into what is actually happening here.